# Cordova (Ionic >= 2) Socket.IO Server

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, websocket, server, socket.io

is there a way to create a Socket.io (websocket) server in a cordova application?

I need to have a socket.io server (websocket) running on my ionic application.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. Please go through [this](https://socket.io/socket-io-with-apache-cordova).

Comment: `var server = require('http').createServer();`
This line not work

Comment: does anyone have an answer for this question??

Answer (score 0):

You can implement socket in IONIC 2 with the help of package name **ng-socket-io**

**Import the package like :**

import { Socket } from 'ng-socket-io';

**Initialize it in constructor**

Then you can call following functions to connect it with socket

this._socket.connect();

this._socket.emit('join_room', "room_name");

Comment: Thanks! but I need a server not a client